# Django add primary key before saving new object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm new to Django and have a Q&A project. For each question you may have multiple tags which already exist or put new ones. The new tags should be created before the question is saved. How do I solve this properly? So far I have:

```
def question_add(request):
    # redirect user to login page if not authenticated
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'account/login.html')

    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.created_by = request.user
            instance.save()

            messages.success(request, 'Question added with success.')
            # redirect to the main page:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            messages.warning(request, 'Please correct the errors.')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = QuestionForm()

    return render(request, 'question/add.html', {'form': form})
```

This should be done prior form.is_valid() or does it exist a magic method for doing this?

Comment: Try it in your `form.is_valid()`, between the two `.save()` functions.

Comment: Side note: To redirect non-authenticated users you could use the login_required decorator: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required

Comment: @AdamStarrh: do you have an example... ? thx

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming `tag` is ManyToMany field for Question model.

Inside `form.is_valid()` to add manyToMany field data.

```
if form.is_valid():
     instance = form.save(commit=False)
     instance.created_by = request.user
     instance.save()
     # returns the list of tag names
     tags = request.POST.get('tags')
     for tag in tags:
         # create if tag not found with given name or return existing tag
         obj, created = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag)
         instance.tags.add(obj)
```

If the Tag is ForiegnKey:

```
if form.is_valid():
     instance = form.save(commit=False)
     instance.created_by = request.user
     tag_name = request.POST.get('tag')
     obj, created = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag_name)
     instance.tag = obj.id
     instance.save()
```

Comment: tag is a ManyToMany field for Question model. But I always get the error message, seems like form is not valid. Using only tags from already existing ones everthing works perfect. Adding new tags, I get the error message...

Comment: Post the specific error? It's possible your form is trying to validate the existence of the tags as objects in your db. You may have to work around that.